# Is appraisal theory of emotion beaten by the theory of constructed emotion?

Tags: emotion, affective-neuroscience

I'm learning narrative comprehension and trying to integrate emotional theories with models for narrative comprehension. Appraisal theory looks like a good fit, but most of the recent studies about emotion are focusing on the theory of constructed emotion. I don't see there's any conflict between these two theories and wonder if the appraisal theory is still popular or valid.
Thanks!

Comment: [This great paper](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1754073909338877) on the history of emotion theories may be helpful: Although constructionist theories are more popular currently, appraisal theorists are still active.

Comment: ResearchGate has [the paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/41896094_Reconstructing_the_Past_A_Century_of_Ideas_About_Emotion_in_Psychology) to download for those without institutional access.

Comment: Thank you guys, this is a very helpful paper. It seems constructionist theory redefined emotion, but doesn't conflict with appraisal theory on how the reaction of emotion is triggered.